Google Apps Script - missing e.postData and BLOB parameters
Could not find any info on my problem below - so posting.
I am uploading a BLOB to a google-apps-script webapp - code and log below.

e.postData is missing on the webapp doPost(e)
e.parameter.**NewsFile** is missing
the e.contentLength indicates the data is received - checked with 1Mb BLOB
the client side formdata indicates NewsFile is being attached
chrome.devtools show correct payload sent to server

I am using FormData because I need to programatically attach files/blobs to the send request.
Any ideas/insight greatly appreciated.
// client code  
function clientTest() {  
    const content = '<q id="a"><span id="b">hey!</span></q>';  
    const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml" });  
    const formdata = new FormData();  
    formdata.append("TestKey", "TestValue");  
    formdata.append("NewsFile", blob);  
    console.log(`client send info :: ${[...formdata.keys()].join(" | ")}`);  
    fetch("webappurl", { method: "POST", body: formdata });  
}  

// client log  
// client send info :: TestKey | NewsFile


// server code - google apps script webapp 
function doPost(e) {
    console.info(`e.keys = ${[...Object.keys(e)].join(" | ")}`);
    console.info(`param.keys = ${[...Object.keys(e.parameter)].join(" | ")}`);
    console.info(`post.length = ${e.contentLength}`); 
}    

// server log
// e.keys = parameters | contextPath | parameter | contentLength | queryString | pathInfo  
// param.keys = TestKey  
// post.length = 684


I think it's possible that FormData is not supported in apps script.  Try using an object instead.

In your client script, you wanted to request multipart/form-data. Unfortunately, in the current stage, Web Apps cannot correctly receive the values of multipart/form-data. In this case, your value is required to be sent as string data. When your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?
Modified script 1:
In this modification, it supposes that the data is a string data.
Javascript:
function clientTest() {  
  const content = '<q id="a"><span id="b">hey!</span></q>';  
  const obj = { content, "TestKey": "TestValue" };
  fetch("webappurl", { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify(obj) });  
}

Google Apps Script:
In the case of the above Javascript, the values content and TestKey can be retrieved as follows.
function doPost(e) {
  // DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", JSON.stringify(e)); // When you use this line, the event object can be seen as a text file.

  const obj = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  const { content, TestKey } = obj;

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}

Modified script 2:
In this modification, it supposes that the data is a binary data.
Javascript:
function clientTest() {  
  const content = '<q id="a"><span id="b">hey!</span></q>';
  const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml" });
  const f = new FileReader();
  f.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  f.onload = d => {
    const buf = new Int8Array(d.target.result);
    const obj = { content: [...buf], mimeType: "text/xml", "TestKey": "TestValue" };
    fetch("webappurl", { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify(obj) });
  }
}

Google Apps Script:
In the case of the above Javascript, the values content, mimeType and TestKey can be retrieved as follows.
function doPost(e) {
  // DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", JSON.stringify(e)); // When you use this line, the event object can be seen as a text file.

  const obj = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  const { content, mimeType, TestKey } = obj;
  DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(content, mimeType, "sample"));

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}

When this script is run, the data is created in the root folder as a file.
Note:

In your showing script, it seems that Web Apps is used. When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

You can see the details of this in my report "Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps (Author: me)".


References:

Web Apps
Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script (Author: me)

Added:
From your following reply,

Ideal would if the e.parameter already contained all the fields

In this case, how about the following modification?
Javascript:
const content = '<q id="a"><span id="b">hey!</span></q>';
const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml" });  
const f = new FileReader();
f.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
f.onload = d => {
  const buf = new Int8Array(d.target.result);
  const obj = { content: JSON.stringify([...buf]), mimeType: "text/xml", "TestKey": "TestValue" };
  const body = new FormData();
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => body.append(k, v));
  fetch("webappurl", { method: "POST", body });
}

Google Apps Script:
function doPost(e) {
  // DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", JSON.stringify(e)); // When you use this line, the event object can be seen as a text file.

  const { content, mimeType, TestKey } = e.parameter; 
  DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(JSON.parse(content), mimeType, "sample"));

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}


By this modification, the values content, mimeType, TestKey can be retrieved from e.parameter.
But, I'm worried that in this case, when the data size of content is large, this approach might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this. So, please confirm it in your situation.


This is not ideal - but I can make this work for now - Thank you @Tanaike
Ideal would if the e.parameter already contained all the fields - ready to use.
Why GAS Webapp automatically still does not handle multipart/formdata is a mystery - that there is no documentation - will trip many developers :(

@Riyaz Mansoor Thank you for replying. I think so. It seems that the current official document for Web Apps is simple. Ref From this situation, I created a report including the specifications of Web Apps I confirmed. https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script

@Riyaz Mansoor As additional information for Ideal would if the e.parameter already contained all the field, I added one more modified script in my answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Once again, Thank you @Tanaike
Quick question though - this method of using JSON ... I could not find the max string length limits to what the JSON object could parse. My use case sees some binary files upto 15MB which will bloat further in the transfer JSON process.
Is there a limit?

@Riyaz Mansoor Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your new question. About this method of using JSON, if you are saying my additional modified script, unfortunately, I cannot know the maximum data size. But, when now I simply tested it, no error occurred for 15 MB, but an error occurred for 20 MB. It seems that the maximum size is from 15 MB to 20 MB. I apologize for this answer to your new question.
